# How to make my nuget package able to "step in"?

Tags: c#, debugging, nuget, nuget-package

Im releasing a nuget package and I'd like that whoever is using it could step into it as if it was his own code.

In order to do that, in the RELEASE configuration (which is the one I use for distribution), I try set the "Debug Information:" to `Embedded` and `Portable` but none did the trick! When I install the package, the pub files are never there...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check out this article on setting up Source Link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/producing-packages-with-source-link/

Answer (score 0):

The answer from memory is:

1. Visual Studio has a config setting for a Symbol Server which must point to source code with the same pdb file produced with the compile used for creating the nuget package.
2. There are different ways to host the symbol server. The easiest is to simply clone the repo from same version the nuget package was created from. Compile that code to generate the pdb. Then point the symbol server config to the bin folder containing the pdb of that compile.
3. Reboot visual studio.

Now try to single step into that code.

The real symbol server is produced as a website. Plenty of doc. On how to do that.

Comment: isn't there a way to pack the symbols with the nuget package?

Comment: Why is that not a good idea? Its seems perfect actually: "Here is the code compiled and optimized, and here also the PDBs and source!" there's no way to mismatch that